# OS X/Linux audio playback with an event-based interface?

Tags: c, linux, macos, audio

I'm working on a streaming audio player for Linux/OS X with a bizarre use case that has convinced me nothing that already exists will work. For the first portion, I just want to receive MP3 data and play it. I'm currently using libmad for decoding and libao for playback. My problem is with libao, and I'm not convinced it's my best option.

In particular, the `ao_play` function is blocking. It doesn't return until the entire buffer passed to it has been played. This doesn't give enough time to decode blocks between calls to ao_play, so the decoding has to be done either entirely ahead of time, or concurrently. Since this is intended to be streaming, I'm rejecting ahead-of-time decoding offhand. (It's conceivable I could send more than an hour's worth of audio data - I don't want to use that much memory.) This leaves concurrency. But while pthreads is standard across Linux and OS X, many of the surrounding libraries are not. I'm not really convinced I want to go to concurrency - so I'm reconsidering my choice of libao.

For my application, the best model I can think of for audio playback would be getting a file descriptor I could select on to get notified when it's ready for writes, then issue non-blocking writes to. (This is due to the rest of the details of the use case, which imply I really want a select loop anyway.)

Is there a library that works on both Linux and OS X that works this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's much hated, [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio) basically works exactly like you describe (using the Asynchronous API, not the simple one).

Unless what you want to do involves low-latencies or advanced sound work, in which case you might want to look at the [JACK Audio Connection Kit](http://jackaudio.org/).

Comment: It's much-hated for good reasons. Especially when OS X is one of my target platforms. But this answer is informative, and I'll accept it if nothing comes along with information I'm happier to see. :)

Comment: @Carl: Agreed... If you're willing to give up on the file descriptor model and go with callbacks instead, take a look at libsdl - [SDL_OpenAudio](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_OpenAudio) takes a callback function that is called every time the sound device needs you to fill its buffer. Also consider [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/)... And take a look at what [SMPEG](http://svn.icculus.org/smpeg/trunk/) is doing with SDL, it might be similar to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) is your one. It has a simple callback driven API. It is cross-platform and low-latency. It is the best solution if you don't need any fancy features (3D, audio-graphs,...).

Comment: This is probably what I'll go with, but it's not really what I was asking for. It'll require some polling to do what I want, but it won't be bad.